# Facebook api to find total reach by city + 10-50 miles radius

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I want to give budget estimation to my user while creating an Advert on Facebook using api. I need total reach to find budget. Is there any API to find *Total Reach* by city name + 10-15 mile radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API for total estimated reach is

```
act_ad_account_id/reachestimate?targeting_spec={targeting_url_encode}
```

## Targeting

```
[
   "geo_locations" => array:1 [
   "cities" => array:1 [
      0 => array:3 [
         "key" => "102356"
         "radius" => "30"
         "distance_unit" => "mile"
      ]
   ],
   min_age => 24,
   max_age => 65,

   ...
   ...
]
```

Convert array into encoded url to replace with `{targeting_url_encode}`. Hope this helps.